# Recibir solo la hora en una base de datos Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Esto solo es una tabla de prueba, llamada prueba, quiero que en el primer valor se ingrese una fecha, luego en los 2 siguiente valores solo se almacene la hora, osea que digamos quede "2:45" a "3:30", pero la verdad no se como hacerlo, busque en varias partes y todos lo hacen con sysdate, pero yo no necesito la hora actual, necesito ingresar la hora que uno quiera

```
 create table prueba(
      fecha_cita date,
      hora_inicio date,
      hora_inicio date);
```

Comment: Fíjate que puedes usar solamente **dos columnas del tipo `DATETIME`** en una pondrías la **fecha y hora de inicio** y en otra la **fecha y hora de fin**. Me dirás, ¿por qué debo hacer eso y por qué **debo tener dos columnas que guarden fechas**? Por un motivo muy simple: imagina un evento que empieza hoy a las 11:59 PM y termina después de la media noche... estaríamos en un escenario donde **la fecha de inicio y de fin son distintas** y no podrás reflejar situaciones como esa sin dos columnas que guarden la fecha. Luego a partir de ahí puedes hacer el cálculo que quieras.

Comment: te entiendo la idea, pero no tendrias algun ejmplo donde se inserte ambas cosas, osea la fecha y hora, despues con un select o algo solo para mostrar la hora

Comment: Hay muchas formas de insertar, por ejemplo: `INSERT INTO prueba (fecha_inicio,fecha_fin) VALUES('2020-03-06 23:59:00', '2020-03-07 00:10:00');` En ese ejemplo, suponiendo que tienes dos columnas `fecha_inicio` y `fecha_fin` y que ambas son del tipo `DATETIME`, se insertarán los valores respectivos. A propósito te puse el caso de una cita que podría empezar un día y terminar otro, para resaltar la importancia de la fecha en ambas columnas...  [Aquí está](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm) toda la documentación relativa a las fechas y hay varios ejemplos.

Comment: a la hora de crear la tabla con los DATETIME, como se deben declarar?

Comment: fecha_inicio DATETIME...... no se la verdad, es la primera vez que trabajo con ese termino

Comment: ya lo intente asi, estoy trabajando sobre en una base de datos oracle y me muestra este error "ORA-00902: tipo de dato no vßlido"

Comment: OK, me confundí con otros manejadores, puedes crear la tabla así: `create table prueba( fecha_inicio date, fecha_fin date);`  y para insertar: `INSERT INTO prueba (fecha_inicio,fecha_fin) VALUES(TIMESTAMP '2020-03-06 23:59:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-03-07 00:10:00');` Prueba y dime si así funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa la función `to_date()`:

```
to_date('2020-03-06 14:45:00', 'RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

El primer argumento es la cadena con el valor deseado, el segundo especifica el formato en el cual se envía el primero.

No tiene caso usar timestamp; ya que Oracle lo convertirá internamente en DATE es mejor ahorrarse dicha  conversión.